# Primefaces make messages or growl modal/confirmable?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, modal-dialog

**Prerequisites:**
- JSF 2.1
- Primefaces 5.2
- Glassfish 3.1

**Story:**
I need my user to confirm FacesMessages of the errortype before he is allowed to keep working. For this i need some sort of modal message or dialog.

**Question:**
Is there some way of makeing a p:messages or a p:growl modal and confirmable?

**What i've tried so far:**
I've created a modal dialog which contains a p:messages component and a button to confirm/close the dialog again. The problematic with this solution is, that i have a lot of cases errormessages are shown and i have to open the dialog for each one individually. Besides that some errormessages are created by validators, some by the "required"-flag and some directly in the code. This makes it even harder to cover all cases. Id prefer to put the function into the component which displays the message (growl or messages).

Comment: have you tried confirmDialog so far?  http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/confirmDialog.xhtml

Comment: @BillyHope: confirmDialog is for confirming actions on buttons etc, not for other purposes like showing messages etc...  Won't work in this case

Comment: @BillyHope besides that it would end up in the same result, haveing to open the dialog for every single message.